# Python: Why do I get u' in the list output?

Tags: python

Why am I getting the u' part in the Output window? Is it something to do with the append function or is this because of some bug in the compiler?
FYI: I'm running this code on the Codecademy's Python compiler.

CODE:

```
hobbies = []

# Add your code below!
for x in range(3):
    hobby = raw_input("Enter your hobby")
    hobbies.append(hobby)
print hobbies

RESULT:
Enter your hobby "Reading"
Enter your hobby "TV"
Enter your hobby "Football"
[u'"Reading"', u'"TV"', u'"Football"']
None
```

Comment: It indicates that the string is stored as unicode. Its just standard and does not influence the data stored in your list in any way

Comment: It's Codecademy's Python compiler problem

Comment: Thanks Dinesh.hmn. Can it be removed

Comment: Do you mean *"can I convert a unicode object into a string object"*? Have you tried searching for information on that topic?

Comment: @JojiThomasEapen Please stop those edits. Names aren't code. I suggest you read what BoltClock♦ (a moderator) has to say about those kinds of edits: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/349538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The u indicates, that the variable is saved as unicode. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Can it be removed or hidden?

Comment: you can try to put `str()` around the hobby in the append function or in the print.

Answer (score 0):

The `u'` just implies that the it's a unicode.
It is not an error.

Try
`type(variable_name)`
to see the type.